# Как оптимизировать запрос к таблицам Wordpress если все параметры для выборки хранятся в 1 таблице

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Разрабатываю магазин на Wordpress с помощью ACF плагина (кастомные поля). Все параметры товара хранятся у него в мета. соответственно при фильтрации в каталоге мне приходится делать JOIN таблицы с мета данными много раз для выборки по всем необходимым параметрам. Меню в каталоге динамическое и составляется в зависимости от того какие параметры есть у товара.

Помогите оптимизировать запросы к БД генерации меню, сейчас они выглядят так:

```
SELECT vozrat_koshek.post_id,vozrat_koshek.meta_value
FROM wp_posts t1
JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_term_relationships.object_id=t1.ID
JOIN wp_postmeta as vozrat_koshek
ON vozrat_koshek.post_id=t1.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as brend
ON brend.post_id = t1.ID
AND brend.meta_key='производитель'
AND (brend.meta_value='137' )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as klass_korma
ON klass_korma.post_id = brend.post_id
AND klass_korma.meta_key='класс_корма'
AND (klass_korma.meta_value='premium' )
JOIN wp_postmeta as osobye_potrebnosti
ON osobye_potrebnosti.post_id = klass_korma.post_id
AND osobye_potrebnosti.meta_key='особые_потребности_кдк'
AND (osobye_potrebnosti.meta_value like '%%s:8:\"kastraty\";%%' )
WHERE vozrat_koshek.meta_key='возрат_кошек' and wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=%d
AND brend.meta_key='производитель'
AND (brend.meta_value='137' )
AND klass_korma.meta_key='класс_корма'
AND (klass_korma.meta_value='premium' ) and t1.post_status='publish'
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `explain текст-вашего-запроса`. отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав [edit] под текстом вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

во первых можно избавиться от дублирующих условий во where

```sql
SELECT vozrat_koshek.post_id,vozrat_koshek.meta_value
FROM wp_posts t1
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id=t1.ID and wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=%d and  t1.post_status='publish'
JOIN wp_postmeta  ON wp_postmeta.post_id=t1.ID  AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key='производитель' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value='137') or (wp_postmeta.meta_key='класс_корма' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value='premium' ))  ....
```

но не понятно про последний джоины по wp_postmeta   некоторые условия друг друга перекрывают уточните условие по данной таблице

Comment: В вопросе where с AND, a у тебя получилось OR. Найдутся все элементы которые удовлетворяют одному из условий.

Comment: в where  они повторяются AND brend.meta_key='производитель'
AND brend.meta_value='137'  они же стоят в LEFT JOIN  и если присмотреться к последнему к 
JOIN wp_postmeta as osobye_potrebnosti
ON osobye_potrebnosti.post_id = klass_korma.post_id он соединяется с  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as klass_korma здесь я совсем логи не вижу

Comment: хорошо опишу проблему 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as brend  к  brend.post_id = t1.ID  и AND brend.meta_key='производитель'
AND (brend.meta_value='137' )  - затем к brend    джонится     wp_postmeta as klass_korma  klass_korma.meta_key='класс_корма'
AND klass_korma.meta_value='premium'  т.е по логике после первого джоина выбрали все пост у которых условие производитель = 137 а потом вней по 2 джоину выбираем по тем же post_id  значение где класс_корма = premium  вы думаете это логично ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно один раз проджойнить таблицу и в where через or прописать все условия, затем группируем по id и выбирать только значения, которые содержат все условия. В having 3 - это количество условий в where.

```sql
SELECT t1.id FROM t1
JOIN t2
WHERE t2.meta_key='производитель' OR t2.meta_key='класс_корма' OR t2.meta_key='особые_потребности_кдк'
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING count(t1.id) = 3
```